# Syntax for OnTriggerEnter validation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why won't these if statements work? When the object with this script attached collides with the object named "Resistor" for example why won't it work?

Code:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    Debug.Log("AAAAAAAA");

    if (collider.gameObject.name == "Resistor")
    {
        resistance = SliderScript.slider.value;
    }
    else if (collider.gameObject.name == "LDR")
    {
        LDRresistance = LDRSliderScript.sliderForLight.value;
    }
    else if (collider.gameObject.name == "Lightbulb")
    {
        Debug.Log("lol");
        GameObject lightGameObject = new GameObject("Light spawned because of collision with a battery");
        Light lightComp = lightGameObject.AddComponent<Light>();

        

        lightComp.intensity = current;
        lightComp.color = Color.white;

        
        lightGameObject.transform.position = Lightbulb.transform.position;
        
        Destroy(lightGameObject, 15);
    }
    else if (collider.gameObject.name == "Battery")
    {
        Debug.Log("Batteryname works");
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post also the exact error message and what line it refers to .. btw have you considered a `switch` ? And also in general instead of going name based I would recommend tags and `CompareTag` .. it uses hashes and is both more reliable (because it warns about typos in tags) and faster than string comparison

Comment: Also how exactly do you know it `doesn't work` ? Have you set breakpoints and debugged what exactly is happening

Comment: Because nothing happens when it collides

Comment: Essentially I want to know what i need to change collider.gameObject.name = “” into to make it work

Comment: I need the syntax changed so when it collides it actually does something

Comment: Checking the name is fine so this should work if the conditions are actually met tbh .. again have you tried to [**Debug your code**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and check where exactly it fails to behave as you'd expect? E.g. is the method called at all? Is it really only the if check failing? => At least the `AAAA..` should get logged right?

Comment: Yeah the AAAA is being output to the console. No other error message shows. The names are all correct.

Comment: So the name is not exactly one of the ones listed. It might have spaces for example

Comment: @BugFinder it updated the code for me, apparently it was out of date or something. However in this image, https://gyazo.com/074433bb9063e4ad5ba42bcdf6656fbb how would I fix the syntax of these if statements so that they work? E.g. what do do i need to put in the <> and the () for the GetComponent

Comment: @derHugo Look at the comment I just posted above please.

Comment: That new code makes no sense at all .. now you are checking **this** objects name (which could simply be done using the property `name` directly as in `if(name == "...")`

Comment: So what do I write so that the code runs when the object collides with the Lightbulb for example, what do I write in the if statement check @derHugo

Comment: Well as said `if (collider.name == "Lightbulb")` should work if the other objects name indeed is `Lightbulb` ... Did you add breakpoints and debug already?

Comment: @derHugo well you see, when I ran collider.name the unity platform came up with an error telling me the code was outdated and that  it will change it for me. When I said yes it changed to the code highlighted in the image. If I try saying no it comes up with an error saying it’s no longer recognised or something similar.

Comment: @SChen the property `name` is inherited by any [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.html) so also by `Collider` .. you probably just named the passed in `Collider` differently so the compiler thinks you refer to the indeed obsolete property `collider` which in old versions provided the collider attached to this GameObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else ever encounters this problem in the future:

The correct syntax is:

```
Private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
If (other.gameObject.name == “whatever”)
{
Debug.Log(“anything”)
}
}
```